# Distinguish session expiration from "forced" logout in Spring with session scoped bean

Tags: session, spring-mvc

I'm trying to handle the session expiration just for logging porpouse.

I've read about the [DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor.html) but it seems to be not called. So I've tried to implement a destroy method for the bean, and this is called.

The problem with this approach is that I cannot distinguish when the bean is destroyed for a session expiration or from a "forced" logout.

I've tried to implement an HttpSessionListener but I cannot access the session bean..

Any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Enrichman you can do implementation something like this:

```
public class HttpSessionRenew implements HttpSessionListener {
   SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

   public HttpSessionRenew() {
        super();
   }

   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        System.out.println("TIME: " + session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
        System.out.println("ID Session "+session.getId()+" create "+session.getCreationTime());
   }

   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();

        // print out the session id
        if(session != null) {
           System.out.println( "Session Id: " + session.getId() );
           synchronized(session) {
              // invalidating a session destroys it
              session.invalidate();
              System.out.println("DESTROYD SESSION");
           }
        }
        System.out.println("ID Session "+session.getId()+" destroyd "+ f.format(new Date()));
   }
 }
```

web.xml

```
 <listener>
     <listener-class>your.fully.qualified.name.HttpSessionRenew</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!-- CONFIGURATION TIME -->
 <session-config>
     <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

**I hope help you :)**